# sql assistance - Generate a report of missing or incomplete values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to generate an automated report where for each case an measure is taken at entry, exit and at 90 days. The database is not entered reliably to be able to use a collection status field marked as 'incomplete'.
Each case should have an entry and exit measure and where they have been held for longer than 90 days a review measure taken.
Fields include:
Product ID
Product Measure - H, H+
Entry date_time
Exit_date_time
Collection_Status  -- complete, incomplete
Collection_Occasion -- entry, exit, review

Where a case is complete and has an exit date but no measure completed there should be row that has the product Id, product measure, entry, exit date, collection status as incomplete and occasion as exit if less than 90days from the entry date but this is missing from the data at present.
Can someone please point me in the right direction to correct this ?

thank you

I have tried - create table but not with much success.
I want a line for each case where entry and exit are on separate lines and the collection status is either complete or incomplete based on whether or not a product measure H or H+ has been completed. The occasion is either at entry (entry date time), exit (exit date time) or 90 days from entry time.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow kirst! i'm not sure about what you meant with "entr," "exit," and "collection." perhaps we should make a sketch of the desired report?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.